# Qt 5.5 Program crash with QStringListModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt noob here! I am attempting to create an iterator to find all .txt files in a given folder, add it to a QStringList and pass it to a QListView. But when I declare a new QStringListModel, I receive

> The program has unexpectedly finished

when I run in Debug and Release mode. Here is the relevant code:

```
QDirIterator it(dir, QStringList() << "*.txt", QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            QStringList fileList;

            // Remove file extension and absolute path from string respectively
            QString filenameRaw = it.next();
            QString filename = filenameRaw.split(".", QString::SkipEmptyParts).at(0);

            // Outputs correctly
            qDebug() << filename;

            fileList << filename;

            // The next line is the problem.
            QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(ui->listView);
            model->setStringList(fileList);
            ui->listView->setModel(model);

        }
    }
```

Probably a silly question, but still something that I can learn from :P

Comment: I would use QFileInfo for the path splitting. Other than that I do not see the crash so I ask are you using Qt binaries that were built for your compiler? You can not use binaries built for a different version of visual studio.

Comment: As far as I know, I have the correct binaries for VS2013. Thanks for the QFileInfo tip!

Comment: One other possible reason. Was Is ui->listView a valid pointer? Do you have the ui setup for your form?

Comment: Just tested for `NULL` so that part is fine. As an experiment, I removed the `ui->listView` parameter and now it runs fine >.< Probably a pointer issue?

Comment: Bugs like this are ridiculously hard to debug and the reason for the crash can be anywhere in the program. You could have corrupted some memory elsewhere in the program and it breaks here. Thorough debugging using specialized tools is needed. On a side note, I don't see a point in putting `while (it.hasNext())` inside an `if` nor in declaring the string list inside the loop, recreating it and the model on each iteration. By doing that you end up with multiple models, but only the last will actually be shown.

Comment: I wouldn't pass `ui->listView` as a parameter when creating your `QStringListModel`, in general the model doesn't need a parent.

Comment: @Nicholas Smith: If you don’t pass ui->listView, you must use other means though to make sure the model isn’t leaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok folks, I managed to figure out the problem. My code (despite the fact it is not really the most optimised at the moment) was actually fine. The issue was that I was *calling the function* that encapsulated this snippet, getFiles(), *before* the UI was setup (*facepalm, I know*):

```
getFiles();
ui->setupUi(this);
```

That resulted in the pointer to ui->listView freaking out. Now the code is like this:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
getFiles();
...
```

Anyways, thanks a bunch for everyone's suggestions to improve the iterator code! I'm sure I'll be back with more!

Edit: I will mark this as answered when the 2-day timer is up.